# Hosting an in-process document database on Windows

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, web-hosting, document-oriented-db, document-database

Are there any document-databases, similar to MongoDB, that run *within* an ASP.NET web application, and could be hosted on a server without any unique machine configuration?

I'm asking this because the hosting provider I'm currently with only support SQL Server 2008 as a database, but I'd like to run my website off a document database.

(Or am I better off going with a specialized database host, such as [MongoHQ](http://mongohq.com))?

Comment: Have you considered moving off your current provider onto say Amazon EC2 so you can have your own virtual machine with full control over what software you run?

Comment: Just that I thought EC2 was for high-scalability applications? Whereas my application at the moment doesn't get much traffic, so maybe it would be a waste of money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently use MongoDB for ASP.NET apps and it works *quite well* ... however we have our own servers.

The question here seems more to do with the ***host*** then MongoDB, or CouchDB, etc.

In this case, yes ... I would say a good option would be to go with a hosting service like MongoHQ (they have quite reasonable rates compared to SQL Server hosts for example.)

That said **why not just get a VPS** that gives you total control of you Windows server?

You can find a Window VPS for reasonable prices and install whatever you want on them ... including MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like VPS is the way to go. Any providers  you can recommend off-hand?

Comment: Sure, while the name is a little funny http://www.kickassvps.com/ is quality as well as http://automatedvps.com (that I use personally) and like a lot.